# Editando exif de uma imagem

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagem

Preciso editar as informações `exif` de uma imagem, como localização e data, por exemplo, mas não estou conseguindo achar nenhuma biblioteca que faça isso com Python 3.4 e Windows. O máximo que eu consegui foi utilizando a Pillow ler essas propriedades, entretanto, quando eu edito e tento salvar a imagem da seguinte forma:

```
image.save(path+'/teste.jpg', 'JPEG', exif=tags)
```

Onde `tags` é um dict, ele diz que o parâmetro exif não aceita o tipo dict, até porque ele é um binário. Eu recupero o exif da seguinte forma:

```
tags = image._getexif()
```

Se eu tentar salvar direto com esse exif, ele apontará o mesmo erro, só que se eu utilizar:

```
tags = image.info['exif']
```

Eu consigo utilizar tags para salvar, entretanto vem em um formato que é impossível editar. Então, existe alguma lib pra Windows e Python 3 que resolva esse problema?

Comment: Acho que o [ExifRead](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead) pode funcionar neste caso.

Comment: @qmechanik, o problema é que eu consigo apenas ler o exif, não consigo editar. ://

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada em [gexiv2](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2) (possui [*bindings* para Python](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2/PythonSupport), 2 e 3). Nunca usei, não sei avaliar se é bom ou não. [Fonte :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400788/resize-image-in-python-without-losing-exif-data#comment39955260_22063878)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, eu dei uma olhada nele, mas, pelo que eu entendi, ele é só pra unix based. ://
O que chegou mais perto até agora foi o pyexiv2 (que é uma versão deprecated do gexiv2), porque funfa pra Windows, mas só python 2.x :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo visto, uma boa opção é a piexif -

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/piexif/1.0.1

Fiz um teste rápido aqui, só instalei e li as informações de uma imagem. Os exemplos na documentação mostram como obter as informações e salva-las de volta usando-a em conjunto com a PIL.

A biblioteca é Python puro, independente de sistema operacional  - teste no Pyhon 3.3 em Linux 64bit.

Comment: vou testar, dando certo, aceito a resposta.